# C# store/load guid list in a file

Tags: c#, file, guid

**Is there a posiblity to store and load a guid list in a file?**

```
List<Guid> targetFaceIds = new List<Guid>();
        foreach (var imageFileName in targetImageFileNames)
        {
            List<DetectedFace> detectedFaces = await DetectFaceRecognize(client, _imagePath + imageFileName, recognitionModel);
            targetFaceIds.Add(detectedFaces[0].FaceId.Value);
        }
```

In my programm I want to store 'targetFaceIds' in a file is that possible and how can I load it back form the file in my programm.

In my 'targetFaceIds' is this:
[image]

Comment: have a look on System.IO.File => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `guid.ToString` to convert it to a string and [`Guid.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.parse?view=net-5.0) to parse it back to a `Guid`:

```
File.WriteAllLines(path, targetFaceIds.Select(g => g.ToString())); // write
targetFaceIds = File.ReadAllLines(path).Select(Guid.Parse).ToList(); // read
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, but which file type whould you use?

Comment: @jonasPamm : you can use any extension  but since it is a text file i would use.txt

Comment: thanks, I think I will use a csv file cause I will save other information to this Guid to

Comment: @jonasPamm: Ok, but then the code aboove doesn't work anymore, you need to use a parser (or `String.Split`) to get the information from each line..